# IntelliJ in Scala asking to implement abstract members in a class inheriting from a concrete class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I am trying to implement tests with scalatest 3.0.5. I created my abstract class defining my setup and my first concrete test class, as suggested [on the official website](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/defining_base_classes).

```
abstract class TestSpec extends FunSuite

class MyFirstTest extends TestSpec {

    test("This is a test") {assert(1 == 1)}

}
```

But then Intellij shows the following error :

> MyFirstTest must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'getTestNameForReport(s:String):String' in 'org.scalatest.Suite'

After reading source code, **FunSuite is a concrete class**.

I tried changing scalatest version to 2.2.6, but the same problem occures. I tried to implement the abstract members but IntelliJ asks to override some methods like `execute`, so this does not seem to be a great idea.

For the records, I am using Maven to build my project, and it builds perfectly. The problem is that I cannot run my tests from the IDE as a warning is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by deleting my project and creating a new one from [this archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-archetype-simple/1.7) with maven. I think my problem was because I messed up my pom somehow.

If you encounter a similar issue, here are some possible fixes (thanks to @Argurth):

- invalidate cache/restart following [those steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html) ([link to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924928/scalatest-v3-why-require-to-implement-converttolegacyequalizer))
- check if the JDK is correctly settled in IntelliJ following steps [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153985/class-must-either-be-declared-abstract-or-implement-converttolegacycheckingequal) (see comments in the first answer).
- Set maven's JDK to your JAVA_HOME. (See the screenshot below, it can be obtained in IntelliJ with File > Setting)

[image: Maven JDK setting]

Answer (score 1):

If everything build perfectly and if you can run the tests outside IntelliJ, it may just be an IDE problem.

Try to follow [those steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html) to invalidate cache/restart and tell me if this solve your problem.

Comment: I already tried this, sorry not to have mentioned it. Sadly it does not work for me. [Link to the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924928/scalatest-v3-why-require-to-implement-converttolegacyequalizer). I prefered creating a new question rather than raising the former from the dead.

Comment: No problem, I will try to reproduce it

Comment: While trying to reproduce your issue, I found another post about a similar one, have your checked that the JDK is correctly set in Intellij ? (here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153985/class-must-either-be-declared-abstract-or-implement-converttolegacycheckingequal) as a reference, check the comments of the first answer)

I can confirm that everything is working for me (Except a missing "with Matchers" to be able to use the should keyword)

Comment: I just checked, IntelliJ's jdk path is set to my JAVA_HOME, and Maven too.

Comment: My bad for the should keyword, I didn't want to make a too complicated example on Stack Overflow. Edited that.

Comment: Found a similar error in my maven configuration. Testing if this resolves my problem.

Comment: This does not work, even after invalidate cache/restart again.

Comment: No problem for the keyword. I'm suspecting it's a configuration problem as I can't reproduce it. It's even more likely to be that if running the tests from the command line is indeed working. I would be curious to know what was the problem once you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete old version of scalatests from Library. ProjectStructure->libraries->[locate scalatest 0.9 ...] - delete